# Node / npm : File to import not found when compiling scss with node-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, npm, node-sass

I'm trying to compile my `sass` with `node-sass` using the following script in my `package.json`:

```
"node-sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed 'src/scss/styles.scss' 'dist/css/bundle.min.css'",
```

My `styles.scss`:

```
@import "bourbon";
@import "neat";

body {background: red;}
```

But when I run `npm run node-sass` I get the following error:

```
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon\n       Parent style sheet: /Users/deangibson/Desktop/personal_site/src/scss/styles.scss\n        on line 1 of src/scss/styles.scss\n>> @import \"bourbon\";\n   ^\n",
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon\nParent style sheet: /Users/deangibson/Desktop/personal_site/src/scss/styles.scss",
  "column": 1,
  "line": 1,
  "file": "/Users/deangibson/Desktop/personal_site/src/scss/styles.scss",
  "status": 1
}
```

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

Shouldn't node just automatically check in the node_modules when it comes to dependencies? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `node` does automatically look for stuff you `require` in your JavaScript files from `node_modules`. You are however executing a command-line app `node-sass` and it does not do that.

You can provide [--include-path](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#command-line-interface) to `node-sass` command line app like this (multiline for readability, needs to be on single line in `package.json`)

```
node-sass 
  --output-style compressed 
  --include-path node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/ 
  --include-path node_modules/bourbon-neat/app/assets/stylesheets/ 
  'src/scss/styles.scss' 
  'dist/css/bundle.min.css'
```

If you write a [render JavaScript file that is executed with `node`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#examples) you can setup the `includePath` by merging the [arrays exported by the `bourbon` modules when you require them](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon#installing-with-npm-and-using-a-node-based-asset-pipeline).